# Async processing of function requests using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to achieve aiohttp async processing of requests that have been defined in my class as follows:

```
class Async():    
    async def get_service_1(self, zip_code, session):
        url = SERVICE1_ENDPOINT.format(zip_code)
        response = await session.request('GET', url)
        return await response

    async def get_service_2(self, zip_code, session):
        url = SERVICE2_ENDPOINT.format(zip_code)
        response = await session.request('GET', url)
        return await response

    async def gather(self, zip_code):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            return await asyncio.gather(
                self.get_service_1(zip_code, session),
                self.get_service_2(zip_code, session)
            )

    def get_async_requests(self, zip_code):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        results = loop.run_until_complete(self.gather(zip_code))
        loop.close()
        return results
```

When running to get the results from the *get_async_requests* function, i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object ClientResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Where am i going wrong in the code? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you await something like `session.response`, the I/O starts, but aiohttp returns when it receives the headers; it doesn't want for the response to finish. (This would let you react to a status code without waiting for the entire body of the response.)

You need to await something that does that. If you're expecting a response that contains text, that would be `response.text`. If you're expecting JSON, that's `response.json`. This would look something like

```
response = await session.get(url)
return await response.text()
```